# Is there any way to have a same changes runtime on different devices?

Tags: flutter, networking, mobile, dart

I'm starting with Flutter and have a question. I want to make an app where you click a button and score increases(I know how to this) but I want it on several devices at once. So when you click another phones see the result right now? How can I implement it?

Comment: so why dont you use server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this could be done with a server, the simplest option would to use Firebase Firestore, here is a complete article on how to do it: https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/using-firebases-cloud-firestore-in-flutter-79a79ec5303a

Firestore is realtime (you can "subscribe" to it and get notified when something has changed.